# Minimum per subgroup in stata

Tags: stata

In Stata, I want to calculate the minimum and maximum for subgroups per country and year, while the result should be in every observation.
Ulitmately, I want to have the difference between min and max as a separate variable.

Here is an example for my dataset:

| country | year | oranges | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USA | 2021 | 100 | 1 |
| USA | 2021 | 200 | 0 |
| USA | 2021 | 900 | 0 |
| USA | 2022 | 500 | 1 |
| USA | 2022 | 300 | 0 |
| Canada | 2022 | 300 | 0 |
| Canada | 2022 | 400 | 1 |

The results should look like this:

| country | year | oranges | type | min(tpye=1) | max(type=0) | distance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USA | 2021 | 100 | 1 | 100 | 900 | 800 |
| USA | 2021 | 200 | 0 | 100 | 900 | 800 |
| USA | 2021 | 900 | 0 | 100 | 900 | 800 |
| USA | 2022 | 500 | 1 | 500 | 300 | -200 |
| USA | 2022 | 300 | 0 | 500 | 300 | -200 |
| Canada | 2022 | 300 | 0 | 400 | 300 | -100 |
| Canada | 2022 | 400 | 1 | 400 | 300 | -100 |

So far, I tried the following code:

```
bysort year country: egen smalloranges = min(oranges) if type == 1
bysort year country: egen bigoranges = max(oranges) if type == 0 
gen distance = bigoranges - smalloranges
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach this directly, as follows:

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input str6 country int(year oranges) byte type
"USA"    2021 100 1
"USA"    2021 200 0
"USA"    2021 900 0
"USA"    2022 500 1
"USA"    2022 300 0
"Canada" 2022 300 0
"Canada" 2022 400 1
end

egen min = min(cond(type == 1, oranges, .)), by(country year)
egen max = max(cond(type == 0, oranges, .)), by(country year)
gen wanted = max - min 

list, sepby(country year)

  b  +------------------------------------------------------+
     | country   year   oranges   type   min   max   wanted |
     |------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |     USA   2021       100      1   100   900      800 |
  2. |     USA   2021       200      0   100   900      800 |
  3. |     USA   2021       900      0   100   900      800 |
     |------------------------------------------------------|
  4. |     USA   2022       500      1   500   300     -200 |
  5. |     USA   2022       300      0   500   300     -200 |
     |------------------------------------------------------|
  6. |  Canada   2022       300      0   400   300     -100 |
  7. |  Canada   2022       400      1   400   300     -100 |
     +------------------------------------------------------+
```

For more discussion, see Section 9 of https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0055

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand the purpose of type 1 and 0, but this generates the exact result you describe in the tables. It might seem convoluted to create temporary files like this, but I think it modularizes the code into clean blocks.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input str6 country int(year oranges) byte type
"USA"    2021 100 1
"USA"    2021 200 0
"USA"    2021 900 0
"USA"    2022 500 1
"USA"    2022 300 0
"Canada" 2022 300 0
"Canada" 2022 400 1
end

tempfile min1 max0

* Get min values for type 1 in each country-year
preserve 
    keep if type == 1
    collapse (min) min_type_1=oranges , by(country year) 
    save `min1'
restore

* Get max values for type 0 in each country-year
preserve 
    keep if type == 0
    collapse (max) max_type_0=oranges , by(country year) 
    save `max0'
restore

* Merge the min and the max
merge m:1 country year using `min1', nogen
merge m:1 country year using `max0', nogen

* Calculate distance
gen distance = max_type_0 - min_type_1
```